# MySQL Error Code: 1349

Tags: mysql

why this query could run in compiler but not work in MySQL and show me this error. What issues and any solution?

```
Error Code: 1349. View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause
```

Examples table:

```
create table if not exists gpsdata
(ID int not null primary key, GPSLat varchar(20), GPSLon varchar(20));
insert into gpsdata values
(1 , 3.214502 , 101.638419),
(2 , 3.214478 , 101.638101);
```

My query

```
create view distances as
select
  prev.id prev_
, curr.id curr_
, prev.gpslat p_lat_
, prev.gpslon p_lon_
, curr.gpslat c_lat_
, curr.gpslon c_lon_
, ROUND( 6353 * 2 * 
    ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((curr.GPSLat - abs(prev.GPSLat)) * pi()/180 / 2),2) 
  + COS(curr.GPSLat * pi()/180 ) * COS( abs(prev.GPSLat) *  pi()/180) 
  * POWER(SIN((curr.GPSLon - prev.GPSLon) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))
  , 2) as distance_km
from (
  select 
    id 
  , gpslat
  , gpslon
  from gps2u_infomation.gps_358899056115705
) prev join gps2u_infomation.gps_358899056115705 curr 
    on prev.id = curr.id - 1
where curr.id >= 1
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to use `SELECT` on `FROM` in a `VIEW`:

> Before MySQL 5.7.7, the `SELECT` statement cannot contain a subquery in the `FROM` clause.
>   **source:** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html

In your case you only select some data from the table (without filter) so you can remove the sub-select and `JOIN` this table directly to itself. See the following `CREATE VIEW` statement:

```
CREATE VIEW distances AS
    SELECT prev.id prev_, 
        curr.id curr_, 
        prev.gpslat p_lat_,
        prev.gpslon p_lon_,
        curr.gpslat c_lat_,
        curr.gpslon c_lon_, 
        ROUND( 6353 * 2 * 
            ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((curr.GPSLat - abs(prev.GPSLat)) * pi()/180 / 2),2) 
            + COS(curr.GPSLat * pi()/180 ) * COS( abs(prev.GPSLat) *  pi()/180) 
            * POWER(SIN((curr.GPSLon - prev.GPSLon) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )),
        2) as distance_km
    FROM gps2u_infomation.gps_358899056115705 prev 
        JOIN gps2u_infomation.gps_358899056115705 curr ON prev.id = curr.id - 1
    WHERE curr.id >= 1;
```